# Why does MATLAB attempt to instantiate abstract properties?

Tags: matlab, validation, oop, abstract, abstract-data-type

There is unexpected (to me) behavior when combining class property validation with abstract properties in MATLAB.  Here is a short example involving three classes:

```matlab
classdef TestClass
    properties (Abstract)
        aprop (1,1) TestClassB
    end
end

classdef TestClassB
    methods
        function obj = TestClassB(a)
            disp(a);
        end
    end
end

classdef TestClassC < TestClass
    properties
        aprop
    end
end
```

Then, when attempting to instantiate a `TestClassC` object, I get the following error:

```
>> TestClassC()
Error defining property 'aprop' of class 'TestClass'. Unable to construct default
object of class TestClassB.
```

Evidently, MATLAB is trying to instantiate the abstract property `aprop` in `TestClass` and then fails due to the lack of a valid zero-argument constructor in `aprop`'s class definition `TestClassB`.  I realize that the zero-argument constructor issue is in theory fixable (although only if you have access to modify TestClassB), but the fact that MATLAB is instantiating an abstract property at all seems very strange.  The first line of the Wikipedia article on abstract types literally states:

> ...an abstract type is a type in a nominative type system that cannot be instantiated directly...

Perhaps this is the only way that MATLAB, as a weakly typed language, can implement property validation, but this is an unfortunate result.

On a side note, if `TestClassB` has a valid zero-argument constructor but is defined to be abstract, you end up falling into the same trap but with a slightly different error:

```
>> TestClassC()
Error defining property 'aprop' of class 'TestClass'. Class TestClassB is abstract.
Specify a default value for property aprop.
```

Is there a good reason for this behavior?

## Edit:

### Additional test-class observations

1. Removing the size validation in `TestClass` eliminates the error.  Evidently, MATLAB has no problem initializing a empty array of objects without a valid zero-argument constructor.  Note: this only works when `TestClassB` is *not* abstract.
2. If `TestClassB` is abstract and `TestClassC` initializes `aprop` *in the property block* with a concrete subclass of `TestClassB`, there is no error (assuming that the concrete subclass has a valid zero-argument constructor).  Note: this is *not* true if `aprop` is instead initialized in `TestClassC`'s constructor.

### Motivating example

[image: Car UML diagram]

The above UML diagram is a typical example of combining inheritance with composition.  `GenericCar` and `GenericEngine` are abstract classes.  `GenericCar` contains a `GenericEngine`, but `Racecar` specifies its engine as a concrete `V8` (which "isa" `GenericEngine`).  Unfortunately, this can't be constructed using property validation in MATLAB since MATLAB will not allow you to re-define the class of an abstract property even if it is a subclass of the original definition.

Suppose you accept that you can't define `engine` in `Racecar` as a `V8`.  Even so, if you don't supply an initial value for `engine` *in the property block* of `Racecar`, MATLAB will throw an error when creating a Racecar object since it will try to initialize `engine` using the abstract type `GenericEngine`.  This is true even if the constructor of `Racecar` initializes engine as a `V8` object.  **This highlights the odd connection between property validation and object instantiation.**

Comment: “This highlights the odd connection between property validation and object instantiation.” But I think it makes sense though. If a property can’t be `[]`, but must be a `GenericEngine`, then when the object is instantiated it must have a `GenericEngine` as property. What is MATLAB supposed to do otherwise? If property validation is what you’re after, why not (1) make a setter that validates the value, or (2) make the property read-only, set in the constructor and never changed?

Comment: By the way, the type of inheritance you’re trying to do here is pointless in MATLAB. MATLAB is not a strongly-typed language, there is no need to use inheritance other than to inherit behavior (check how they implemented the handle base class and similar classes). You can structure your code much more simply, not requiring that `engine` be a subclass of an abstract class `GenericEngine`, but requiring that it have specific behavior (it implements certain functions).

Comment: PS: to validate an object has the required methods in your setter function, use [`ismethod`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismethod.html).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Honestly, I'm not sure what MATLAB should do. Maybe leave the property empty and apply the validation only when actually setting the property?  That would have trade-offs too of course, such as instantiating an object with properties that are not strictly valid.  Or, it could at least hold off on validating properties until after the constructor has executed, but maybe that would have side effects too.  As for the work around, I agree that there are other, perhaps less "direct" ways of achieving the same or similar results, but then what's the point of property validation?

Comment: @CrisLuengo You bring up some interesting points about how to best use OOP in a weakly-typed language like MATLAB.  Can you point me to info you mention about the handle base class?  As for requiring specific behavior rather than using abstract classes, isn't that exactly what abstract classes are for, defining the methods that must be implemented?  It seems like manually checking for method names in an object is a roundabout way of implementing the same functionality.

Comment: There's no way to leave a property not assigned. MATLAB doesn't have a NULL pointer. It does have empty arrays, but you specifically state you want this to be a 1x1 array, so an empty array is not legal. And indeed, the object is instantiated before the constructor is called, not at the end of executing the constructor. Why? Who knows! MATLAB's OOP has some strange things going on. But at least it's internally consistent, you might not agree with the design, but it works.

Comment: Regarding the use of abstract classes, there's a philosophical question there. And I think the reasoning is different for strongly and weakly typed languages. In MATLAB and Python, the usual process is to just let the user pass an object, the function tries to use it, if it fails, you tell the user why it failed. This is what they call "duck-typing": I don't care what it is, but I'll call the "quack()" method on it. If that fails, it's your problem. It's a weakly-typed language so you don't need to do type validation. This implies that virtual base classes have a different use here.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that two questions should be answered:

1 - "Evidently, MATLAB is trying to instantiate the abstract property `aprop`  in `TestClass`. So why does MATLAB attempt to instantiate abstract properties?"

According to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/validate-property-values.html) (emphasis is by me):

> You can define property validation for abstract properties. The validation applies to *all subclasses* that implement the property.

MATLAB is trying to instantiate the property `aprop` in `TestClassC` that is a *concrete* subclass of `TestClass`. But it uses the same validation rules that is used in `TestClass`. The `aprop` property of `TestClassC` isn't abstract.

2 - "If `TestClassB` ... is defined to be abstract, you end up falling into the same trap..."

Referring to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/abstract-classes-and-interfaces.html):

> *abstract class* — A class that cannot be instantiated, but that defines class components used by subclasses.

`TestClassC` uses the same validation rules that is used in `TestClass`. It tries to instantiate its `aprop` member that is of class `TestClassB` but `TestClassB` is abstract and cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Thanks for following up.  I guess I should be more clear that I understand what MATLAB is doing, but I find that MATLAB's implementation eliminates most of the fruitful use cases for abstract properties.  The point of an abstract property is to be a placeholder for a concrete definition in a subclass.  Therefore, the definition in the superclass should never need to be instantiated.  Basically, MATLAB treats property validation as a "pre-constructor", forcing the properties to be instantiated at object creation regardless of "abstract-ness". 
 This isn't as clear from the documentation.

Comment: I like you interested to understand what is the MATLAB behavior and tried to explain the behavior and shared my findings with you and possibly other users. I like you believe that there are much of places for the documentation to be improved. If you think it is what you want please accept the answer. As you have edited the question it appears that I also should edit my answer and extend the discussion that may be opinion based. If you have any more questions I think it is better to send them as new posts.